# How to unwind from UINavigationController to UIViewController?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, stack-unwinding

I'm trying to use an unwind segue from a `UINavigationController` subclass to a `UIViewController` subclass. My issues arise arise (I believe) because my navigation controller is the root view controller of my `UIWindow`. I attempted to set my `UIViewController` as the root and then modally present the navigation controller before my `AppDelegate` finishes launching, but that doesn't work because the view is not added to the hierarchy.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Is there anyway to attach a segue to the top view controller of the navigation controller? I have a fairly large storyboard and would like to avoid repeating myself on multiple controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently struggling with using unwind segue past navigation controller myself too but maybe that article I found can help you. It describes (with GitHub project attached) how to use unwind segues whilst under the aegis of a UINavigationController:
https://github.com/simonmaddox/CustomUnwindSegue/tree/master

PS - Regarding your Edit: If you can get it to work following SimonMaddox steps in the link I suggested, the method should then work from any ViewController under the Navigation Controller I think.